# loop in javascript [from X to Y]

Tags: javascript

I'm starting to learn javascript and I have the first problem. In the task I want to perform a loop that prints the numbers from the user-specified range, example: for values: 2 and 10, prints in the div: 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10. My code:

```
function loopChecking() {
'use strict';
var numberA = document.getElementById("numberA").value,
    numberB = document.getElementById("numberB").value,
    i = 0,
    result = "";

for (i = numberA; i <= numberB; i += 1) {
    result += i + " ";
}
document.getElementById("numbers").innerHTML = result;
}
```

below is the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Loop</title>
    <script src="numbers.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="numberA" />
    <input type="text" id="numberB" />
    <input type="submit" value="Show" onclick="loopChecking()" />
    <div id="numbers"></div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for the help, MD.

Answer (score 8):

You need to convert `numberA` and `numberB` to Numbers first

```
var numberA = +document.getElementById("numberA").value, //observe unary + 
    numberB = +document.getElementById("numberB").value, //observe unary +
```

**Demo**

```js
function loopChecking() {
  'use strict';
  var numberA = +document.getElementById("numberA").value,
    numberB = +document.getElementById("numberB").value,
    i = 0,
    result = "";

  for (i = numberA; i <= numberB; i += 1) {
    result += i + " ";
  }
  document.getElementById("numbers").innerHTML = result;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="numberA" />
<input type="text" id="numberB" />
<input type="submit" value="Show" onclick="loopChecking()" />
<div id="numbers"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `numberA`and `numberB` are not seen as number. You need to parse them

```
var numberA = parseInt(document.getElementById("numberA").value,10),
    numberB = parseInt(document.getElementById("numberB").value,10),
```

Comment: Also specify a radix.
parseInt(val, 10);

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to chech if your numbers are actually numbers.

Also you could add check for (`numberA < numberB`) or specify the loop according to numberA and numberB values.

```js
function loopChecking() {
  var numberA = Number(document.getElementById("numberA").value),
      numberB = Number(document.getElementById("numberB").value),
      result = "";


  if (numberA && numberB) {    
    for (var i = numberA; i <= numberB; i++) {
      result += i + ' ';
    }
  } 
  
  document.getElementById("numbers").innerText = result;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Loop</title>
    <script src="numbers.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="numberA" />
    <input type="text" id="numberB" />
    <input type="submit" value="Show" onclick="loopChecking()" />
    <div id="numbers"></div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/saffrons/8u2bh7dx/) is a working fiddle.

I used `parseInt()` on the `document.getElementById("numberA").value`

Answer (score 0):

Other answers parsing explicitly string as number are correct but in HTML5 and especially for mobile users there is better to do. You have to set `input` type as `number` not `text` if you expect user to enter only number. And you would need to use the property `valueAsNumber` of `HTMLInputElement`.

So e.g in HTML markup:

```
<input type="number" id="numberA" />
```

And in javascript:

```
var numberA = document.getElementById("numberA").valueAsNumber
```

```js
function loopChecking() {
  'use strict';
  var numberA = document.getElementById("numberA").valueAsNumber,
    numberB = document.getElementById("numberB").valueAsNumber,
    i = 0,
    result = "";

  for (i = numberA; i <= numberB; i += 1) {
    result += i + " ";
  }
  document.getElementById("numbers").innerHTML = result;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="numberA" />
<input type="number" id="numberB" />
<input type="submit" value="Show" onclick="loopChecking()" />
<div id="numbers"></div>
```

Regarding readability and user experience, this is for sure better.